# LUIS gives 403 error “Out of call volume quota.” when testing in portal with using Authoring Resource F0

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

As I am trying to test LUIS app, it is throwing 403 error with this message:*"Out of call volume quota for LUIS.Authoring F0 pricing tier. Please retry after 9 days. To increase your call volume switch to a paid tier."*
I am using the Azure Authoring resource key tier F0 which has a [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-limits?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#authoring-resource-limits) of 1 million/month, 5/second. Across all apps, we have made only 2310 API calls this month and we have not made more than 5 per second. I am not using the prediction resource key as it has a monthly limit of 10 thousand.

I got a similar error couple of days ago in which the message was to try again after 11 days but it started working later for a day and then again got the error to try after 9 days. It makes me wonder if there is any other limit on a daily or weekly basis or is this due to some other issue?

I read similar posts here but couldn't figure out a resolution. It would be great if anyone can share any insights on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The 1 million/month is for *authoring transactions* only. These would be the programmatic calls to get intent lists, add applications, train applications, etc. This doesn't apply to actually testing the application through your in-portal testing. The limit for testing predictions with the authoring key is only **1,000/month**. You can just create a free tier prediction resource and associate it to your LUIS app which will upgrade you to 10,000/month.

Microsoft has good [documentation on LUIS Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription?tabs=portal) if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @billoverton for the response. I was using Power Automate to test and the power automate connector for LUIS was only accepting the authoring key, which is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/luis/#known-issues-and-limitations). So instead, I have directly called the API and used the prediction key and that has fixed the issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue while reading test predicitions Json. I have a prediction resource created within the app. How do I use the prediction key? Can you please explain this further.?